# How do I declare the codeName of a spreadsheet in XML format?

Tags: excel, xml, schema, spreadsheet

I am currently looking at writing a template document in XML to be opened in Microsoft Excel. This has hidden worksheets and some formulas going on.

What I would like to do is to declare the 'codeName' in my XML template.  However I cannot find the code to do this.

If I try and reverse engineer this by declaring the name in the VB code editor in excel, and then saving the file as an XML spreadsheet, when inspecting the code, there is no reference to the codeName. Is this possible to declare in XML?

I have seen some reference to codeName declared using SheetPr (Sheet Properties), but I do not believe this is part of the Microsoft office schema.
The start of my XML file is as below, do I need to change this to a different schema to edit the codeName.  Thank you in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <ActiveSheet>2</ActiveSheet>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
```

Comment: I have changed the .xlsx file extension to .zip to inspect the individual xml files contributing to the file. Looking at these I can see where the codeName is specified for the individual sheets. Ideally I would like to produce just the one .xml file. So my question is how do I adapt the schema and references above to be able to use the codeName reference in-line?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trial and error and searching online, I finally found the answer.

After saving the spreadsheet in Excel as an XML file (2003 Spreadsheet), launch a code editor to view the source code.

Under the  tag enter:

```
<CodeName>Sheet1</CodeName>
```

Replacing 'Sheet1' with the desired codeName.